# Фильтр списка статусов Скайпа на сайте

Tags: html, dle, skype

День добрый! У меня вот родилась идея реализовать на сайте под управлением DLE такую фишку: на одной странице будет список пользователей Скайпа, которые, к примеру, работают на нашем предприятии и мне хотелось бы, чтобы пользователь, который зашел на сайт и открыл страницу с этими контактами, видел только тех, кто находиться онлайн, а те, кто оффлайн, они бы на странице не отображались! Для отображения статуса Скайпа на сайте, я хочу использовать такой вот способ:

```
<p>
<a href="skype:ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ?chat"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://МОЙ_САЙТ/js/skype.js"></script>Skype:ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ</a>
<p>
```

В самом файле skype.js ничего необычного не будет, там будет только ссылка типа

```
http://mystatus.skype.com/smallicon/ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ
```

и защита от кеширования карртинки браузером через **Math.random()**. Кто знает, как реализовать это все и через что? В каком направлении мне двигаться вообще?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю сделать так:

Сохранить оффлайн картинку на сервере, из php получить ее md5() и сохранить.
Потом при выводе юзеров из того же php получать ее и сравнивать md5, если аналогичны - пропускаем.

```
function getSkypeImage($user) {
  // получение картинки, curl/fsockopen
  return $image;
  }
$offlineHash = 'строка md5';
foreach ($skypeUsers as $user) {
  $uimg = getSkypeImage($user);
  if (md5($uimg) == $offlineHash) continue;
  echo '<p>
<a href="skype:'.$user.'?chat"><img src="http://mystatus.skype.com/smallicon/'.$user.'" />Skype: '.$user.'</a>
<p>';
  }
```

Только эта штука нагрузку неплохую сделает, потому советую ее мин на 5 хотя бы кэшировать.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery в помощь, создайте плагин - который будет убирать offline пользователей при загрузке страницы. В принципе, если не трудно. Можете до вечера подождать, к вечеру библиотеку напишу - и скину Вам.

Comment: сдается мне, jquery офигеет определять картинки о_О

Comment: К выше приведенному код - можно сделать для динамичности связку Jquery + php. jquery - получает список, отправляет массивом на сервер, сервер возращает только online юзеров.